# HTML/CSS Header Formatting Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm working a project which consists of creating a web application. Currently, I'm focusing on the general design and layout of the website. First of all, I want a horizontal dark grey header on the top. Below that, I want two columns, one with a navigation bar, and one with the content.

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDTZL.png)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFf9W.png)

Below is my code and I'm not sure what's causing the issue of the dark header on top not showing up.

Full CSS file: https://pastebin.com/kpUHV71Z

```html
<section class="management">
    <div class="header-div">
        <img src="Golf.png" class="management-logo" height="50" width="50">
        <h1 class="impact" id="management-header">Management Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="left left-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h3>Staff</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you provide full css

Comment: I attached the full CSS just now.

Comment: I've copy-pasted your code on a jsfiddle and your header shows up just fine ... https://jsfiddle.net/49m5395n/ so it's probably something else on your code. Please provide full CSS

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a display and a width to your header

```
.header-div {
    background-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    height: auto;
     width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will make the header behave as a block and let you navigation adjust

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    font-family: verdana;
}
 
.selection-menu {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
 
#special-button {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
#special-button2 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 400px;
}
 
#header {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
}
 
#author {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
 
.club-selection {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
 
.input-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
 
.impact {
    font-family: Montserrat;
}
 
.index-section {
    background-color: rgb(242,242,242);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-top: 50px;
}
 
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
 
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 2px;
}
 
.management {
    background-color: rgb(242,242,242);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-top: 50px;
}
 
h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 
.separate {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
 
.buttongroup {
    display: inline;
}
 
input {
    display: inline;
}
 
button {
    background-color: #555555;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
 
button:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
 
input {
    border: none;
    height: 3%;
}
 
#appdescription {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
 
.inline-alignment {
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 
img {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
 
.header-div {
    background-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    height: auto;
     width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
 
.left {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
 
.right {
    margin-left: 25%;
}
 
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
 
.management-logo {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
 
#management-header {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
 
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
}
 
li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
 
.left-nav {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<section class="management">
    <div class="header-div">
        <img src="Golf.png" class="management-logo" height="50" width="50">
        <h1 class="impact" id="management-header">Management Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="left left-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h3>Staff</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to left-floated elements (logo and title) and no clears on your header-div, so it effectively has zero height.

So adjust with a clearfix, or use inline-block or flexbox instead of floats.

```
.management-logo {
margin-right: 20px;
display:inline-block;
}

#management-header {
margin-top: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
margin: 0;
display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49m5395n/13/

Answer (score 0):

I really love `display: flex;` and thats why I recomend it for everyone. It isn't too much heavy and saves a LOT of styling. I sugest you to study it.

Anyway, here is my contribution:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  font-family: verdana;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background: #555;
}

.canvas {
  display: flex;
}

.navigation {
  width: 25%;
}

.content {
  width: 75%;
}

/* YOUR CODE BELOW*/

.selection-menu {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#special-button {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#special-button2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

#header {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}

#author {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.club-selection {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.input-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.impact {
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

.index-section {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin-top: 50px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 2px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.separate {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.buttongroup {
  display: inline;
}

input {
  display: inline;
}

button {
  background-color: #555555;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

input {
  border: none;
  height: 3%;
}

#appdescription {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.inline-alignment {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header-div {
  background-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  height: auto;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.left-nav {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <img src="golf.png" height="50" width="50">
  <h1 class="impact">Management Dashboard</h1>
</header>

<div class="canvas">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Content</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```